# Laravel 5.4 Migration Error Server Network Interfaces The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: php, laravel-5, sqlsrv

I have a fresh install of laravel 5.4 on windows 10 which I am using with SQL localdb and I am unable to get it to connect to the database. Another version of laravel 5.2 that I copied on this computer is connecting just fine.

I get the following error when I run "php artisan migrate":

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The system cannot find the file specified.
   (SQL: create table "migrations" ("id" int identity primary key not null, "migration" nvarchar(255) not null, "batch" int not null))



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces: The system cannot find the file specified.
```

This error was resolved by installing the ODBC 13 driver and SQL Command Line tools but resulted in the new following error:

```
[Illuminate\Database\QueryException]
  SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces:  (SQL: select * from sysobjects where type = 'U' and name = migrations)



  [PDOException]
  SQLSTATE[08001]: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 13 for SQL Server]SQL Server Network Interfaces:
```

I am using:
PHP 7.0.10
SQL Server Express LocalDB Command Line Tool Version 13.0.1601.5
Laravel Framework 5.4.25
Microsoft Windows 10 Home Version: 10.0.15063 N/A Build 15063\

So, how do I fix this?

Comment: Is the SQL service running? What does running  'sqlcmd -S ".\mssqllocaldb"'  show?

Comment: I tried that and the command line tools weren't installed. Apparently neither were the ODBC 13 drivers. I have now installed both. This is sqlcmd -S "(localdb)\MyInstance" command that works for me as "MyInstance" is the localdb instance I am using. I am now getting a different error @btl . I have updated the question?